# Updated multiple records column value of based selected id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In products table I have fields like

```
id   product_name   product_value   quantity    status
1     abc             10000           50        received
2     efg             5000            15        shipment
3     hij             850             100       received
4     klm             7000            20        shipment
5     nop             350             50        received
```

I can select multiple rows at a time. And here I selected `id=2,4` and need to change the `status='received'`. How to do multiple update at single time in rails?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Product.where(id: [2, 4]).update_all(status: 'received')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all products that have a status of `'shipment'`, you can use:

```
Product.where(status: 'shipment')
```

From here, you can set all to `'received'`, or iterate through them and select only the ones you want to make changes to.